# Replace variable with a blank identifier in Go package

Tags: go

When I replace the variable `resp` on line 25 I get the error `no new variables on left side of :=` and the code won't compile. How can I replace the variable with a blank identifer to throw away the response?

Thank you in advance!

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/storage/azblob"
)

func main() {

    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Authentication failure: %+v", err)
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    //data := "Hello world!"
    blobURL := "https://STORGEACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/CONTAINER/BLOB.txt"

    blockBlob, err := azblob.NewBlockBlobClient(blobURL, cred, nil)

    resp, err := blockBlob.Delete(ctx, nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failure: %+v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Comment: Note that `resp` is declared only once in the above code so the error ain't coming from that. For discarding variables you can use `_`. For avoiding the error, but not discarding the variables, simply use a new name or, use `=` instead of `:=`.

Comment: Oh, it was because I was using `:=` instead of `=`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Short-form declarations require you to declare at least one new variable. When you replace `resp` with `_`, this is no longer satisfied because `err` is already defined. So:

```
    _, err = blockBlob.Delete(ctx, nil)
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply, the error message now makes sense. Thank you. :)